# MessageController (Text) Set Body not setting the body. (iOS 6)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

```
-(IBAction)SendTextTapped:(id)sender{

  if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    MFMessageComposeViewController* messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    __block NSString *fullA = [[NSString alloc] init];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    CLLocation *newerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:21.1700
                                                      longitude:72.8300];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newerLocation
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                 if (error) {
                   NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                   return;
                 }

                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                 {
                   CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                   NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
                   placemark.addressDictionary;

                   NSLog(@"%@ ", addressDictionary);
                   NSString *address = [addressDictionary
                                      objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                   NSString *city = [addressDictionary
                                     objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                   NSString *state = [addressDictionary
                                      objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
                   NSString *zip = [addressDictionary
                                    objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];

                  NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip);

                   //NSLog(fullA);
                   fullA=(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip);
                 }
               }];
  [messageController setBody:fullA];
  [self presentModalViewController:messageController animated:YES];
  }
  else {

    NSLog(@"%@" , @"Sorry, you need to setup mail first!");
  }

}
```

I have attempted using __block, or everything I could find in online tutorials.

This does print out the full address in NSLog. However, no matter what I have tried this does not show up for `[messageController setBody:(@"%@ %@ %@ %@",city, state, address, zip)];`

and using (setBody:@"Hello") works just fine...

I'm sure there is something small that I can do to fix this, but everything I have tried has failed. Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you are doing the way you are doing it. The call to `reverseGeocodeLocation` is asynchronous. You end up presenting the message controller long before you get back the address information. This is why the body is always empty.

You need to modify the code to create and display the message composer from within the completion handler (but you must dispatch the code on the main queue).

```
- (IBAction)SendTextTapped:(id)sender{
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        CLLocation *newerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:21.1700 longitude:72.8300];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newerLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                return;
            }

            NSString *body = @"";
            if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
                placemark.addressDictionary;

                NSLog(@"%@ ", addressDictionary);
                NSString *address = [addressDictionary
                                   objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                NSString *city = [addressDictionary
                                   objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                NSString *state = [addressDictionary
                                   objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
                NSString *zip = [addressDictionary
                                   objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];

                NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip);

                //NSLog(fullA);
                body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip];
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                MFMessageComposeViewController* messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
                messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                [messageController setBody:body];
                [self presentModalViewController:messageController animated:YES];
            });
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@" , @"Sorry, you need to setup mail first!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that that address lookup could take some time. You may want to display an activity indicator (or something similar) to let the user know that something is happening. Otherwise there could be a long delay between tapping the button and the message composer appearing. In fact, the user could leave the current view controller which will likely result in a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringWithFormat` in order to set body with different objects, something like this

```
[messageController setBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@",city, state, address, zip];
```